# Python - Using socket to send data to every IP address on a network

Tags: python, sockets

What I am looking for is for my python server, which is just a private server that responds to client input, for when it starts to send it's IP address to every IP on a network on port 4005. I do not know a way to figure out exactly which IPs are valid to send to on a network.

Here is the code that I thought would work, but raises an exception:

```
File "E:\Python\server client comms\messageEveryIP.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.bind((curIP, listeningPort))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

In my case it errors out on 192.168.1.2 because there is no machine on that IP.

```
import socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
listeningPort = 4005

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

i = 1
while i < 255:
    curIP = '192.168.1.' + str(i)
    listeningAddress = (curIP, listeningPort)
    s.bind((curIP, listeningPort))
    s.sendto(host.encode('utf-8'), listeningAddress)
    s.close()
    i += 1
```

Comment: try and except the `OSError` and the code will run. might not be the best solution.

Comment: @echo It does remove the exception, but now the code just sends the data to 192.168.1.1 (my router) 255 ish times.

Comment: `Exception: OSError, IP not valid in context
192.168.1.1
Exception: OSError, IP not valid in context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\server client comms\messageEveryIP.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.bind((curIP, listeningPort))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

I added the exception print line myself.

Comment: you have to create new socket for every IP

Comment: `bind()` is used to assign socket to local network card (LAN/WiFi) in your computer - it is not used to connect to other computer. And you have to use IP of your network card or `0.0.0.0` to use all network cards in your computer. You should use `'192.168.1.' + str(i)` in `sendto()`

Comment: don't `close()` socket if you want to send next information.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, removed `close()`, and replaced `listeningAddress` with `'192.168.1.' + str(i)` in `sendto`, and I moved the `i += 1` to the top so it increments properly, but I still get the Requested address is not valid in it's context, even though it is a valid IP address (.180 is on my phone)
`Exception: OSError, IP not valid in context
192.168.1.180`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some mistakes and very unreadable names of variables.

- `bind()` is used to assign server to local network card - not to client IP - and use it only once - before loop
- don't close socket because (as I rember) it will need to create socket again

---

```
import socket

#server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # this gives me `127.0.1.1` because I have it in `/etc/hosts`
server_ip = '192.168.1.13'  # <-- IP of my WiFi card on server
server_port = 4005

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#s.bind( (server_ip, server_port) ) # assign server to one local network card
s.bind( ('0.0.0.0', server_port) )  # assign server to all local network cards

text = f'{server_ip}:{server_port}'
print(text)

# --- loop ---

for i in range(1, 255):
    client_ip = f'192.168.1.{i}'
    client_port = 4005

    print(f'{client_ip}:{client_port}')

    s.sendto(text.encode('utf-8'), (client_ip, client_port))

# --- after loop ---

s.close()  # only if you will no use this socket any more
```